# How can i define multiplication on Nats?

Tags: haskell

I'm having a problem with defining `mult` on `Nat`s in Haskell.

```
mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult  Z    m = Z
mult  m    Z = Z
mult (S m)(S n) = S (mult m n)
two    = S (S Z)
three  = S (S (S Z))
```

I get these results:

```
> mult Z three             
Z
> mult two three
S (S Z)
> mult three three
S (S (S Z))
```

Which part is causing the problem here?

Solved.

Nat : Natural

Z : Zero

mult : multiply

```
mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat

mult Z    m = Z                       -------- 0*m = 0

mult (S n) m = plus m (mult n m)      -------- (n+1)*m = m+nm


> mult Z three             
Z
> mult two three
S (S (S (S (S (S Z)))))
> mult three three
S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S Z))))))))
```

my cell was having problem with equation

**mult (S m)(S n) = S (mult m n)**

it was incorrect equation same as (1+m)*(1+n) = 1 + m*n

so i changed equation as

**mult (S n) m = plus m (mult n m)** --- (n+1)*m = m+nm

Thanks for who answered my question. I finished easily thanks to your help.

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what the last line of `mult` means?

Comment: From what you know of algebra, does this equation look right to you? `(1+x)*(1+y) = 1 + x*y`. That's what you've written as your third defining equation for `mult`.

Comment: Hint: how can you calculate `(x+1)*y` in terms of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Our professor abbreviate multiply -> mult. so I used it.

Comment: and thank you for comment, i think i found what was problem. thx

Comment: @4320 If you have solved your problem, please add an answer below explaining what you discovered and how you fixed it. This way, future visitors who have a similar problem can learn from your discoveries. (It may seem odd at first to both ask and answer a question, but it is considered perfectly polite and even desirable here on SO.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank for your information :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about this more carefully. Instead of pattern matching on both sides, let's just do one. So:

```
mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult  Z    m = -- TODO: 0 * m = ???
mult (S n) m = -- TODO: (1 + n) * m = ???
```

Let's start with `0 * m`, which is obviously `0`:

```
mult  Z    m = Z
```

Now for `(1 + n) * m`. From simple algebra, this is `m + n*m`. So, assuming you've already made a `plus` function somewhere, this is easy:

```
mult (S n) m = plus m (mult n m)
```

Note that an implementation of `plus` is a requirement for this. If you understand this, try re-writing `mult` by pattern matching on both sides.